# How to send "null" or empty value to database through PHP?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid that with date columns that post in format 0/0/0000 or if empty send "null" to my php file to then insert to MYsql column. It posts "null" but does not send "null" command to database column. What I'm I missing? Firephp says that at this point my date column inputs are all '"1969-12-31"'. What can I do to post "null" correctly to these columns?
******UPDATE:** Here is the var dumb for $_REQUEST:****

```
array(12) {
  ["name"]=>string(24) "FABTECH B2B Presentation"
  ["id_continent"]=>string(6) " Ramon"
  ["lastvisit"]=>string(10) "12/31/2104"
  ["cdate"]=>string(9) "8/22/2014"
  ["ddate"]=>string(9) "9/14/2014"
  ["notes"]=>string(69) "B2B machines are C1 AJ and HG ATC.  Waiting for part data from Yoshi."
  ["hello"]=>string(2) "No"
  ["mydate"]=>string(4) "null"
  ["oper"]=>string(4) "edit"
  ["id"]=>string(3) "184"
  ["PHPSESSID"]=>string(32) "93de884f9e02d507ff3662f63149f9f3"
  ["SQLiteManager_currentLangue"]=>string(2) "10"
}
```

My code:

```
    $crudColumns =  array(
    'id' =>'id'
    ,'name'=>'name'
    ,'id_continent'=>'id_continent'
,'lastvisit'=>'lastvisit'
    ,'cdate'=>'cdate'
    ,'ddate'=>'ddate'
    ,'notes'=>'notes'
    ,'hello'=>'hello'
    ,'mydate'=>'mydate'

);

function fnCleanInputVar($string){
    //$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    return $string;
    }
    /*----====|| GET and CLEAN THE POST VARIABLES ||====----*/
    foreach ($postConfig as $key => $value){ 
        if(isset($_REQUEST[$value])){
            $postConfig[$key] = fnCleanInputVar($_REQUEST[$value]); 
        }
    }
    foreach ($crudColumns as $key => $value){ 
        if(isset($_REQUEST[$key])){
            if ($key == 'lastvisit' || $key == 'cdate' || $key == 'ddate' || $key == 'mydate' ) {
                $crudColumnValues[$key] = '"'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST[$key])).'"';
            } else {
                $crudColumnValues[$key] = '"'.fnCleanInputVar($_REQUEST[$key]).'"';
            }
        }
    } 
    FB::info($crudColumnValues, "Dates");
    /*----====|| INPUT VARIABLES ARE CLEAN AND CAN BE USED IN QUERIES||====----*/

Mysql query
case $crudConfig['update']:
        /* ----====|| ACTION = UPDATE ||====----*/
        if($DEBUGMODE == 1){$firephp->info('UPDATE','action');}
        $sql = 'update '.$crudTableName.' set ';
        /* create all of the update statements */
        foreach($crudColumns as $key => $value){ $updateArray[$key] = $value.'='.$crudColumnValues[$key]; };
        $sql .= implode(',',$updateArray);
        /* add any additonal update statements here */
        $sql .= ' where id = '.$crudColumnValues['id'];
        if($DEBUGMODE == 1){$firephp->info($sql,'query');}
        mysql_query( $sql ) 
        or die($firephp->error('Couldn t execute query.'.mysql_error()));
        break;
```

Comment: Where is the SQL query? You need to put a literal `NULL` into the query.

Comment: @Eric But if the database column is nullable, you can put `NULL` instead of a date.

Comment: Or you should use a parametrized query, and send a PHP `null` value to it.

Comment: @Barmar looks like it's not nullable ...

Comment: also, if you don't want to insert the date fields that aren't KEY fields, why pass them? Just remove them before inserting them..

Comment: i inserted the MYSQL Query. @Barmar I am a newbie. Could you insert an answeer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the parameter from the grid is `null`, and put `NULL` into the database instead of the date.

```
foreach ($crudColumns as $key => $value){ 
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$key])){
        if ($key == 'lastvisit' || $key == 'cdate' || $key == 'ddate' || $key == 'mydate' ) {
            if ($_REQUEST[$key] == 'null') {
                $crudColumnValues[$key] = 'NULL';
            } else {
                $crudColumnValues[$key] = '"'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST[$key])).'"';
            }
        } else {
            $crudColumnValues[$key] = '"'.fnCleanInputVar($_REQUEST[$key]).'"';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I still get the same result. "NULL" is not inserted into the database. It looks like  `$crudColumnValues[$key] = 'NULL';` is not sent down.

Comment: Maybe the grid is actually sending the string `NULL`, not a PHP null value. I've changed my code to check for that. If that doesn't work, show what `$_REQUEST` contains when it's supposed to put a null date into the DB.

Comment: Ok it comes out $_REQUEST=null but it still comes out 1969-12-31

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to your post. Put it in the post, not a comment, so you can format it readably. It's important to use `var_dump` so we can tell whether `null` is a string or the null datatype. So don't use `echo` or `print_r`.

Comment: Got it. I'll do it shortly. Thank you

Comment: So when sent as date everything is fine but when sent as   ["mydate"]=>string(4) "null" is where the problem is.

Comment: My answer was almost right, I just needed to make `'null'` lowercase. Try it now.

Comment: mydate: "1969-12-31" comes out like this not null. I ge this aswell Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web-master/jqGridCrud.php on line 118</b><br />
null

Comment: query: update demo set id="181",name="Total Solutions Q4",id_continent=" Paul",lastvisit="2014-07-15",cdate="2014-10-10",ddate="2014-12-05",notes="hjtnhn??????jhn",hello="Yes",mydate=null where id = "181"

Comment: I edited the wrong one. The one that matters is the one being compared with `$_REQUEST`, because PHP is case-sensitive. MySQL keywords are case-insensitive, so that one doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you may be confusing empty with null. An empty string will be interpreted as "" whereas null will be interpreted as "null", big difference. Try this.

**EDIT:**
After looking at the PHP manual it seems that if you try to add a null value to an array key it is changed to "".

First of all, create your array like this

```
['mydate'] => ''
```

Change your date formatting.

```
foreach ($crudColumns as $key => $value){ 
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$key])){

if ($key == 'lastvisit' || $key == 'cdate' || $key == 'ddate' || $key == 'mydate' ) {       
    if (strtotime($value)) {
       $value = '"'.date('Y-m-d', $value).'"';
    } else {
      $value = "";
    }
} else {
    $crudColumnValues[$key] = fnCleanInputVar($_REQUEST[$key]);
}
```

Also, part of the issue is that you are specifying the keys but you need to be changing the value.

Comment: actuall I would prefer it to send as empty.I tried it but it still comes out the same.

Comment: It depends on the way your DB column is setup but you can't send an empty string to a datetime column, you will get the default date you are seeing. But, if you have the default on the column set as say NULL or empty, it should allow you to insert an empty value.

Comment: By changing the default value on the date column no date will be inserted unless it is specifically added with your query.

Comment: damn. My date columns are already default set to NULL. I tried both of your suggestions but it's still the same result `['mydate'] =>
'"1969-12-31"'`

Comment: Are the variables with dates inserting properly? The problem may be that you are not inserting the date in the correct format. Try echoing the date before you enter it into the database and post it here.

Comment: Seems that you can ignore my last edit, I realized that you are using the quotes for your sql query. Much easier to put them directly into your query than in the variable.

Comment: The dates are inserting perfectly. its just when the value in "mydate" column in jqgrid is empty then it does not submit properly. I was experimenting with sendig either "null" or empty from the jqgrid but its the same result.

Comment: No error. Everything submits perfect but when mydate is empty from grid it always returns '"1969-12-31"'

Comment: According to that error, your issue is not with the mysql insert, it's saying the mydate var doesn't exist at all. Try creating the array like this instead:
['mydate'] => "" or ['mydate'] => "NULL" then it at least has a default value until it's changed.

Comment: No error. Everything is submitted properly. I added an update.

Comment: Ok, well the bottom line is that mysql doesn't like the value you are inserting. I'm willing to bet it's not empty or null so it defaults to 1969-12-31. It's more than likely happening because of the way you are formatting it. I wouldn't do it like this `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST[$key]))`. Separate the two functions, because by doing it this way you are assuming there will always be a date when obviously there won't. See my edited answer.

Comment: Something else that concerns me is '"1969-12-31"', do you noticed the two sets of quotes there. This tells me that you are adding double quotes into the database.

Comment: I don't understand.It always inserts into database perfectly. I never had problem until I had to send empty or null values.

Comment: `query: update demo set id="181",name="Total Solutions Q4",id_continent=" Paul",lastvisit="2014-07-15",cdate="2014-10-10",ddate="2014-12-05",notes="hjtnhnjhn",hello="Yes",mydate="1969-12-31" where id = "181"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61243/discussion-between-eternalhour-and-newhistoricform).